# Image loading with JSON service

Tags: android

I have an app where people can set pictures as wallpaper but its really slow because pictures are very big. This app load pictures and then when i want to see it again it has to load again.
What to do to make it faster? I use Json service. My pictures are from server. i am using universal image loader.

Answer (score 1):

Theres 2 types of cache in android, the memory cache and the disk cache. You should use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) its a library that implement both and is very easy to use (1 line of code).

Comment: I have never heard about picasso. But can i add this into my existing app and can i continue to use json service to load pictures from server? Anyway, thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Yes, check the website, you just need to pass the url and the imageView in which you want to put the image to a picasso function. By the way, i suggest you to use google gson to parse json, it automatically creates an object from a json.